# How to run all tests with pytest ignoring all markers

Tags: python, pytest

We have a test repo containing tens of thousands of tests, and hundreds of custom markers. Is there any way that I can run all the tests (or at least collect only), ignoring all the markers?
It sounds like a very basic question, but unfortunately, I searched online could not find an answer.

Comment: How do you run them with a specific marker?

Comment: currently I have to specify certain value of a marker, say pytest --platform=windows. If I wanna run window and linux then have to specify both of them. There are hundreds of criteria in there that I can't exaustedly specify in CLI.

Comment: Did you try without `--platform=windows`?

Comment: `--platform` looks like a custom marker, in which case you may have to look at its implementation

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just override the `-m` argument with an empty string

```
pytest -m ""
```